# Task Scheduler Arguments

Tags: task-scheduler

Are there any parameters defined for Task Scheduler arguments?  Specifically, I'd like to send in the current location of the task.

For example:  If I've got a task under **Task Scheduler Library > My Application > Folder Name**, I'd like to send **Folder Name** in as an argument to the action - something like %(CurrentLocation).  Does Task Scheduler support anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a PowerShell call and use .NET to get the machine name.

For "Program/script:" enter:

```
powershell
```

For "Add arguments (optional):" enter

```
/command "& { notepad $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry(\"\").HostName) }"
```

Replace `<your_command>` with the command you want to execute. The first argument to it will be the hostname.

Comment: So, I'm not looking for the machine name; I'm looking for the folder in which the task resides.  I'll modify the question to be more clear.